# Serving outside web-app static files using spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to have a file download feature, basically serving the file using spring MVC.

When i looked the documentation, all examples are related to serving files within web-app.

Does spring MVC framework support serving static contents which are outside web-app?

OR do we have any other alternate option using spring?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to serve file that reside outside of the webapp root. In fact, you do it just as you guessed in your comment:

so

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/mydocs/**" location="file:/opt/mydocs/css/" />
```

in SpringMVC the prefix inside the location instructs the lookup strategy, and there are four types

```
classpath: - resources loaded from the classpath.
file: - resources loaded as a URL, from the filesystem.
http: - resources loaded as a URL.
(none) - resources relative to the ROOT
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

Comment: Thank you for the solution in details. I am getting 15:50:59.753 [pool-4-thread-1] ERROR o.o.p.w.e.w.internal.WebAppPublisher - Error deploying web application
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc] . I am getting error even with proper schema. What could be the issue?

Comment: well, this a (separate) configuration issue. Most obvious is that you're missing a  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" attribute in the root beans tag of your servlet configuration. In addition you should add inside your    xsi:schemaLocation element the following http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd  just adjust your spring mvc version

Comment: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

Comment: It is giving problem with schema mentioned above. It should work, but i dont know why it is not working very strange.

Comment: if you have a hard time figuring it out, you can post as a separate question